# I am not able to connect tomcat with eclipse

Tags: java, jsp, administrator, eclipse-3.5

My eclipse used to work fine but now I am no longer the administrator of my computer(I no longer have administrator priveledges) and i see that my already installed and working eclipse is now showing errors in my jsp files of the application which it didn't used to show before..
also I am not able to connect to tomcat server which seperately can be started normally but not inside eclipse.....
Is this something to do with my not being administrator anymore of is it something else....

would highly appreciate the help.....

I have now been able to run my tomcat server without admin previledge but problem of many files showing error still persists.........
the below written jsp code is showing error in all the files....:
<%
pageContext.getRequest().setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String label =  pageContext.getRequest().getParameter("rswitb1");
if(label==null)label="";
else label = label.replaceAll("<", "<").replaceAll(">", ">");
%>

I am not able to get what the problem ....
if anyone could help...

Comment: Request administrator privileges.  You _are_ a developer.

Comment: That I can request for..........I just wanted to confirm that was it because of not being an administrator only?

Comment: Are you getting some kind of errors? If yes, please share!

Comment: Its not showing any error......When i try to run any page in my application on server it simply writes in the console that Tomcat server[Stopped]........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection to the external tomcat should be using only TCP/IP port 8080, there is no reason why a non-admin user should not be able to do that.

It's possible that your tomcat password has changed (or hasn't been set up at all)

There is a troubleshooting section at [the eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#Troubleshooting) (if you are using WTP, that is)

Comment: Thats what i ws trying to enquire because the same tomcat version used to work fine when i was working as an admin but not it is not connecting......

Answer (score 2):

First,check out the tomcat server is on:    *"netstat -an"*  to 
find that whether the port8080 is used(if you didn't assign another server port.).

Comment: eclipse's not working may be due to environmental variable（without pathclass_path,java_home）

Comment: I did set all the environment variables.............but still error persists.....

Answer (score 0):

check out  whether the server is on(netstat -an).
Maybe 8080 is used by tomcat.
You'd better reinstall tomcat as non administrator.